# Bluemix: Error:Failed to launch chaincode spec(Could not get deployment transaction for

Tags: ibm-cloud, blockchain

I am trying to get the chaincode_example02 from IBM to work, but I am struggling with some issues.

I connected with a Bluemix starter network. I have waited longer to query, but without any success. Now, I am reading the peer log and I have the following questions:

1. Do I need to add / import the peer and shim from my local go working directory?
2. What does the `launchAndWaitForRegister failed Error starting container: API error (500)` mean?

> OUT - 20:45:56.877 [consensus/pbft] ProcessEvent -> INFO 1ca[0m
>   Replica 0 batch timer expired  OUT - 20:45:56.877 [consensus/pbft]
>   sendBatch -> INFO 1cb[0m Creating batch with 1 requests  OUT -
>   20:45:56.879 [consensus/pbft] executeOne -> INFO 1cc[0m Replica 0
>   executing/committing request batch for view=0/seqNo=31 and digest
>   YrYAFLUeCUaZSwV85WOvOzd8rDHIeryEt5612Tck8gjf+jVU+Xh1y+3OE+rpz08VPPSbbwt7vR0wsrU1NzvXoA==
>   OUT - [31m20:45:58.930 [dockercontroller] deployImage -> ERRO 1cd[0m
>   Error building images: The command '/bin/sh -c go install
>   build-chaincode && cp
>   src/build-chaincode/vendor/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/core.yaml
>   $GOPATH/bin && mv $GOPATH/bin/build-chaincode
>   $GOPATH/bin/8482db43feb10640d37c343bf6d50feb29ba21da196075a721d6489eb1fab616'
>   returned a non-zero code: 1
>
> OUT - [31m20:45:58.930 [dockercontroller] deployImage -> ERRO 1ce[0m
>   Image Output:  OUT - ********************  OUT - Step 1 : FROM
>   hyperledger/fabric-baseimage  OUT -  ---> 21cb00fb27f4  OUT - Step 2 :
>   COPY . $GOPATH/src/build-chaincode/  OUT -  ---> Using cache  OUT -
>   ---> f4e8d401945d  OUT - Step 3 : WORKDIR $GOPATH  OUT -  ---> Using cache  OUT -  ---> 4cb1d635a080  OUT - Step 4 : RUN go install
>   build-chaincode && cp
>   src/build-chaincode/vendor/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/core.yaml
>   $GOPATH/bin && mv $GOPATH/bin/build-chaincode
>   $GOPATH/bin/8482db43feb10640d37c343bf6d50feb29ba21da196075a721d6489eb1fab616
>   OUT -  ---> Running in 85da9ebe80f0
>
> OUT - [91msrc/build-chaincode/chaincode_example02.go:30:2: cannot
>   find package "github.com/hyperledger/fabric/protos/peer" in any of: 
>   OUT -     /opt/go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/protos/peer (from
>   $GOROOT) OUT -
>     /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/protos/peer (from
>   $GOPATH) OUT - [0m OUT - ******************** OUT - [31m20:45:59.688
>   [dockercontroller] Start -> ERRO 1cf[0m start-could not recreate
>   container API error (500): Error: image
>   library/8b01ce9efeff42d48ce02c3c53356c1d-vp0-8482db43feb10640d37c343bf6d50feb29ba21da196075a721d6489eb1fab616:latest
>   not found
>
> OUT - [31m20:45:59.688 [chaincode] Launch -> ERRO 1d0[0m
>   launchAndWaitForRegister failed Error starting container: API error
>   (500): Error: image
>   library/8b01ce9efeff42d48ce02c3c53356c1d-vp0-8482db43feb10640d37c343bf6d50feb29ba21da196075a721d6489eb1fab616:latest
>   not found  OUT - 20:45:59.689 [consensus/pbft] execDoneSync -> INFO
>   1d1[0m Replica 0 finished execution 31, trying next  OUT -
>   20:47:56.546 [consensus/pbft] ProcessEvent -> INFO 1d2[0m Replica 0
>   batch timer expired OUT - 20:47:56.547 [consensus/pbft] sendBatch ->
>   INFO 1d3[0m Creating batch with 1 requests  OUT - 20:47:56.548
>   [consensus/pbft] executeOne -> INFO 1d4[0m Replica 0
>   executing/committing request batch for view=0/seqNo=32 and digest
>   HfK1r9YKy8VyEKJPyWbRITJalorskEzDb9xuxqsLvBQNWw1ePsH6W4NZtBHmm+Wgo5Q2TgumvLpApyPSvD5xWQ==
>   OUT - 20:47:56.549 [consensus/pbft] execDoneSync -> INFO 1d5[0m
>   Replica 0 finished execution 32, trying next

---

the chaincode

```
/*
Copyright IBM Corp. 2016 All Rights Reserved.

Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
You may obtain a copy of the License at

         http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
limitations under the License.
*/

package main

//WARNING - this chaincode's ID is hard-coded in chaincode_example04 to illustrate one way of
//calling chaincode from a chaincode. If this example is modified, chaincode_example04.go has
//to be modified as well with the new ID of chaincode_example02.
//chaincode_example05 show's how chaincode ID can be passed in as a parameter instead of
//hard-coding.

import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"

    "github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/shim"
    pb "github.com/hyperledger/fabric/protos/peer"
)

// SimpleChaincode example simple Chaincode implementation
type SimpleChaincode struct {
}

func (t *SimpleChaincode) Init(stub shim.ChaincodeStubInterface) pb.Response {
    fmt.Println("ex02 Init")
    _, args := stub.GetFunctionAndParameters()
    var A, B string    // Entities
    var Aval, Bval int // Asset holdings
    var err error

    if len(args) != 4 {
        return shim.Error("Incorrect number of arguments. Expecting 4")
    }

    // Initialize the chaincode
    A = args[0]
    Aval, err = strconv.Atoi(args[1])
    if err != nil {
        return shim.Error("Expecting integer value for asset holding")
    }
    B = args[2]
    Bval, err = strconv.Atoi(args[3])
    if err != nil {
        return shim.Error("Expecting integer value for asset holding")
    }
    fmt.Printf("Aval = %d, Bval = %d\n", Aval, Bval)

    // Write the state to the ledger
    err = stub.PutState(A, []byte(strconv.Itoa(Aval)))
    if err != nil {
        return shim.Error(err.Error())
    }

    err = stub.PutState(B, []byte(strconv.Itoa(Bval)))
    if err != nil {
        return shim.Error(err.Error())
    }

    return shim.Success(nil)
}

func (t *SimpleChaincode) Invoke(stub shim.ChaincodeStubInterface) pb.Response {
    fmt.Println("ex02 Invoke")
    function, args := stub.GetFunctionAndParameters()
    if function == "invoke" {
        // Make payment of X units from A to B
        return t.invoke(stub, args)
    } else if function == "delete" {
        // Deletes an entity from its state
        return t.delete(stub, args)
    } else if function == "query" {
        // the old "Query" is now implemtned in invoke
        return t.query(stub, args)
    }

    return shim.Error("Invalid invoke function name. Expecting \"invoke\" \"delete\" \"query\"")
}

// Transaction makes payment of X units from A to B
func (t *SimpleChaincode) invoke(stub shim.ChaincodeStubInterface, args []string) pb.Response {
    var A, B string    // Entities
    var Aval, Bval int // Asset holdings
    var X int          // Transaction value
    var err error

    if len(args) != 3 {
        return shim.Error("Incorrect number of arguments. Expecting 3")
    }

    A = args[0]
    B = args[1]

    // Get the state from the ledger
    // TODO: will be nice to have a GetAllState call to ledger
    Avalbytes, err := stub.GetState(A)
    if err != nil {
        return shim.Error("Failed to get state")
    }
    if Avalbytes == nil {
        return shim.Error("Entity not found")
    }
    Aval, _ = strconv.Atoi(string(Avalbytes))

    Bvalbytes, err := stub.GetState(B)
    if err != nil {
        return shim.Error("Failed to get state")
    }
    if Bvalbytes == nil {
        return shim.Error("Entity not found")
    }
    Bval, _ = strconv.Atoi(string(Bvalbytes))

    // Perform the execution
    X, err = strconv.Atoi(args[2])
    if err != nil {
        return shim.Error("Invalid transaction amount, expecting a integer value")
    }
    Aval = Aval - X
    Bval = Bval + X
    fmt.Printf("Aval = %d, Bval = %d\n", Aval, Bval)

    // Write the state back to the ledger
    err = stub.PutState(A, []byte(strconv.Itoa(Aval)))
    if err != nil {
        return shim.Error(err.Error())
    }

    err = stub.PutState(B, []byte(strconv.Itoa(Bval)))
    if err != nil {
        return shim.Error(err.Error())
    }

    return shim.Success(nil)
}

// Deletes an entity from state
func (t *SimpleChaincode) delete(stub shim.ChaincodeStubInterface, args []string) pb.Response {
    if len(args) != 1 {
        return shim.Error("Incorrect number of arguments. Expecting 1")
    }

    A := args[0]

    // Delete the key from the state in ledger
    err := stub.DelState(A)
    if err != nil {
        return shim.Error("Failed to delete state")
    }

    return shim.Success(nil)
}

// query callback representing the query of a chaincode
func (t *SimpleChaincode) query(stub shim.ChaincodeStubInterface, args []string) pb.Response {
    var A string // Entities
    var err error

    if len(args) != 1 {
        return shim.Error("Incorrect number of arguments. Expecting name of the person to query")
    }

    A = args[0]

    // Get the state from the ledger
    Avalbytes, err := stub.GetState(A)
    if err != nil {
        jsonResp := "{\"Error\":\"Failed to get state for " + A + "\"}"
        return shim.Error(jsonResp)
    }

    if Avalbytes == nil {
        jsonResp := "{\"Error\":\"Nil amount for " + A + "\"}"
        return shim.Error(jsonResp)
    }

    jsonResp := "{\"Name\":\"" + A + "\",\"Amount\":\"" + string(Avalbytes) + "\"}"
    fmt.Printf("Query Response:%s\n", jsonResp)
    return shim.Success(Avalbytes)
}

func main() {
    err := shim.Start(new(SimpleChaincode))
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Error starting Simple chaincode: %s", err)
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a link to the chaincode_example02 example so that we know what you are referencing?

Answer (score 0):

1. I am assuming you are using the SDK (HFC) client to deploy your chaincode. You do not need to import the peer and shim code from your local go working directory, but you do need to have a /vendor folder with the code inside it. 
   Should look something like this ==> [vendor structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lVV1f.jpg)

The vendor folder contents would look like :

```
./vendor
./vendor/github.com
./vendor/github.com/hyperledger
./vendor/github.com/hyperledger/fabric
./vendor/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/consensus
./vendor/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/consensus/controller
./vendor/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/consensus/executor
./vendor/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/consensus/helper
./vendor/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/consensus/helper/persist
./vendor/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/consensus/noops
./vendor/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/consensus/pbft
./vendor/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/consensus/util
```

........continues..... (basically the peer and shim code all here)

The deployment will use the chaincode.go + vendor folder to create the docker container for chaincode execution.

The errors you are receiving is because it cannot find the code needed to build the chaincode container.

2. The "launchAndWaitForRegister failed Error starting container: API error (500)" error is just telling you that the deployment request was unable to build the chaincode container properly.

Hope this helps!